# How to execute a vbscript from another vbscript?

Tags: syntax, vbscript

For example, if I have two vbscript files: `A.vbs` and `B.vbs`. I would like the vbscript in B.vbs to execute A.vbs, such peudo-code would look like the following:

```
'B.vbs
execute("A.vbs")
```

Just as simple as this line, but I couldn't really find a valid syntax to accomplish such task. Hope someone could help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim oShell 
Set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "name_of_vbs_file_here.vbs"   
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Comment: that will execute a script yes but without any interaction with the calling script

Answer (score 0):

The following will execute a.vbs as it were a part of the calling script itself

```
include "a.vbs" 

sub include(script)
  dim fso, file
  set fso = createObject ("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
  if fso.FileExists (script) then 
    set file = fso.OpenTextFile (script)
    executeGlobal file.ReadAll ()
    file.Close 
    set file = nothing 
  end if 
  set fso = nothing 
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim Shell
Set Shell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run "a.vbs"
```

You can also spice it up a little by adding things like "SendKeys" or other Shells.

Answer (score 0):

```
createobject("wscript.shell").run"a.vbs"
```

or if your files aren't in the same folder

```
createobject("wscript.shell").run"""C:\Users:\User:\YourFolder\a.vbs"""
```